# How do I make this menu selection more concise?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code for my school project and I feel there is a way to make it shorter, but I'm not sure how ?

```
menuchoice = input()
if menuchoice == 1:
    menuchoice1()
elif menuchoice == 2:
    menuchoice2()
elif menuchoice == 3:
    menuchoice3()
elif menuchoice == 4:
    menuchoice4()
elif menuchoice == 5:
    menuchoice5()
elif menuchoice == 6:
    menuchoice6()
```

Comment: A good answer depends on what all of those functions do. Why do you not simply pass in the value to a common function (eg: `menuchoice(input())`)?

Comment: Also note that in the code you have, in Pyton 3 the `input()` function returns a **string**. not an integer, so **none** of your `if` and `elif` conditions will be true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store those functions in an array:

```py
choices = [
  menuchoice1,
  menuchoice2,
  ...
]
```

And then get them by index:

```py
menuchoice = int(input())
choices[menuchoice - 1]()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map of the choice with the corresponding action.

```
choice_action_map = {
    1: menuchoice1,
    2: menuchoice2,
    3: menuchoice3,
    4: menuchoice4,
    5: menuchoice5,
    6: menuchoice6,
}
```

and then execute the corresponding action based on the input like this

```
choice_action_map[int(input())]()
```

Also, the action keys can be strings with the action names which will make your code more readable.

Comment: @martineau I don't think that is the case.

`In [141]: def foo():
     ...:     print("bar")
     ...:

In [142]: c = {1: foo}

In [143]: c[input()]()
1
bar`